# Reading a file, pulling linked data and writing to new file using curl

Tags: curl

I am learning curl and have so far figured out how to pull data and write to a file. However what i would love to be able to do is read a list of IDs from an excel file and pull the linked data in to a new file.

For example we have a database of 300,000 people. Each person has a unique id. I want data for 6,000 of those people, but don't want to pull all 300,000 people and use excel vlookup. How do I get curl to read the unique ids from a file and give me back their names and email addresses from the database?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a job for curl, this is a job for a scripting/programming language, use 1 of those. (python? php? java? c++?)